# Nested select in Mongoose Query

Tags: sql, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**I am trying to convert SQL into Mongoose query and I find it quite confusing**. This is my schema.Basically I want to fetch data for the last 7 days from the today

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var RequestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  pickup_person_name:String,
  dest_person_name:String,
  pickup_person_phone:String,
  dest_person_phone:String,
  tranx_status:String,
  order_status:String,
  pickup_longitude:String,
  pickup_latitude:String,
  pickup_location_name:String,
  pickup_date:Date,
  dest_longitude:String,
  dest_latitude:String,
  dest_location_name:String,
  price:String,
  item_to_deliver:String,
  rider_id:String,
  rider_name:String,
  order_number:String,
  payment_mode:String
},{ autoCreate: true});
mongoose.model('Request', RequestSchema);
```

This is the query I want to convert to Mongoose.

```
SELECT pickup_date, count(*) FROM (SELECT pickup_date as event_date FROM requests where DATE(pickup_date) >= (CURRENT_DATE -  '7 DAYS')   ) GROUP BY pickup_date ORDER BY pickup_date

I expect to have a list like 
[ { event_date:27/08/2020,count:8},{ event_date:26/08/2020,count:9},{ event_date:25/08/2020,count:9}]
```

Comment: can you post data from your db?

Comment: I expect to have a list like from the db
[ { event_date:27/08/2020,count:8},
{ event_date:26/08/2020,count:9},
{ event_date:25/08/2020,count:9}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          "$pickup_date",
          {
            "$subtract": [
              "$$NOW",
              604800000
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: {
          $year: "$pickup_date"
        },
        month: {
          $month: "$pickup_date"
        },
        day: {
          "$dayOfMonth": "$pickup_date"
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: 1,
      _id: 0,
      event_date: {
        "$concat": [
          {
            "$toString": "$_id.day"
          },
          "/",
          {
            "$toString": "$_id.month"
          },
          "/",
          {
            "$toString": "$_id.year"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dE0Dtq7TYki)

Comment: I have order_status as Done,New. For those dates. I want to add them to the array so that we get [ { event_date:27/08/2020,count:8,new:2,done:1},{ event_date:26/08/2020,count:9,,new:1,done:1},{ event_date:25/08/2020,count:9,,new:2,done:1}]
How will I add it to the aggregate.Your query worked

Comment: Like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/b791bTa0nXG